# Create a class with array properties better approach

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I'm successfully create a class and save it to the page.I used special php charackets here.Without using those is there anyway to create a class using any magic method in OOP

Please see this bellow hole code.I update it in full

```
<?php

$title = null;
$online = null;
$offline = null;
$email = null ;
$metadescription = null;
$metakeywords = null ;
$copyright = null;
$pard_host = null;
$pard_database = null;
$username = null;
$password = null ;

if(isset($_POST["title"])){$title = $_POST["title"];}
if(isset($_POST["online"])){$online = $_POST["online"];}
if(isset($_POST["offline"])){$offline = $_POST["offline"];}
if(isset($_POST["email"])){$email = $_POST["email"];}
if(isset($_POST["meta-description"])){$metadescription = $_POST["meta-description"];}
if(isset($_POST["meta-keywords"])){$metakeywords = $_POST["meta-keywords"];}
if(isset($_POST["copyright"])){$copyright = $_POST["copyright"];}
if(isset($_POST["pard_host"])){$pard_host = $_POST["pard_host"];}
if(isset($_POST["pard_database"])){$pard_database = $_POST["pard_database"];}
if(isset($_POST["username"])){$username = $_POST["username"];}
if(isset($_POST["password"])){$password = $_POST["password"];}  



class pard_admin_Config{


    function __construct($TITLE,$ONLINE,$OFFLINE,$EMAIL,$METADESCRIPTION,$METAKEYWORDS,$COPYRIGHT,$HOST,$DATABASE,$USERNAME,$PASSWORD) {
        $this->TITLE = $TITLE;
        $this->ONLINE= $ONLINE;
        $this->OFFLINE = $OFFLINE;
        $this->EMAIL = $EMAIL;
        $this->METADESCRIPTION = $METADESCRIPTION;
        $this->METAKEYWORDS= $METAKEYWORDS;
        $this->COPYRIGHT = $COPYRIGHT;
        $this->HOST = $HOST;
        $this->DATABASE= $DATABASE;
        $this->USERNAME = $USERNAME;
        $this->PASSWORD = $PASSWORD;
    }
}

$adminConfig  = new pard_admin_Config($title,$online,$offline,$email,$metadescription,
$metakeywords,$copyright,$pard_host,$pard_database,$username,$password);

$pardConfig = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pard', "root", "");
if(isset($pardConfig)){
    echo $adminConfig->TITLE;

    }
$SQL =<<<'EOD'
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pard_admin_config(
title varchar(255) NOT NULL,
online varchar(100),
offline varchar(100),
email varchar(100),
metades varchar(200),
metakey varchar(200),
copyright varchar(200),
pard_host varchar(100),
pard_database varchar(100),
username varchar(100),
password varchar(100)
)
EOD;

$pardConfig->query($SQL);


$stmt = $pardConfig->prepare("INSERT INTO pard_admin_config (title, online, offline, email, metades, metakey, copyright, pard_host, pard_database, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
title=values(title), online=values(online), offline=values(offline), email=values(email), metades=values(metades), metakey=values(metakey), copyright=values(copyright), pard_host=values(pard_host), pard_database=values(pard_database), username=values(username), password=values(password)");
 $ConfigData = array($adminConfig->TITLE,
 $adminConfig->ONLINE,
 $adminConfig->OFFLINE,
 $adminConfig->EMAIL,
 $adminConfig->METADESCRIPTION,
 $adminConfig->METAKEYWORDS,
 $adminConfig->COPYRIGHT,
 $adminConfig->HOST,
 $adminConfig->DATABASE,
 $adminConfig->USERNAME,
 $adminConfig->PASSWORD);
$stmt->execute($ConfigData);


$classProperties =  "<?php \n class PardFactory { \n public \$TITLE = '$adminConfig->TITLE';\n public \$ONLINE = '$adminConfig->ONLINE';\n public \$OFFLINE =  '$adminConfig->OFFLINE';\n public \$EMAIL =  '$adminConfig->EMAIL';\n public \$METADESCRIPTION =   '$adminConfig->METADESCRIPTION';\n public \$METAKEYWORDS =  '$adminConfig->METAKEYWORDS';\n public \$COPYRIGHT =  '$adminConfig->COPYRIGHT';\n public \$HOST =  '$adminConfig->HOST';\n public \$DATABASE =  '$adminConfig->DATABASE';\n public \$USERNAME =  '$adminConfig->USERNAME';\n public \$PASSWORD =  '$adminConfig->PASSWORD';\n } \n ?>";

$file = fopen("../../pard_config/configuration.php","w");
fwrite($file,$classProperties);
fclose($file);
?>
```

**This code create a class**

```
<?php 
 class PardFactory 
 { 
     public $TITLE = '';
     public $ONLINE = '';
     public $OFFLINE =  '';
     public $EMAIL =  '';
     public $METADESCRIPTION =   '';
     public $METAKEYWORDS =  '';
     public $COPYRIGHT =  '';
     public $HOST =  '';
     public $DATABASE =  '';
     public $USERNAME =  '';
     public $PASSWORD =  '';
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: Although the name of your class implies it's a 'Factory', this is NOT a factory pattern. Setting the properties of yout Object should be done inside the constructor

Comment: You can always try using [`get_object_vars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: How  to write another file with pardFactory class ? can we extend make sense ?

Comment: First of all, this is not really OOP. Instead of creating a class and filling it with public properties (thus violating encapsulation, which is the whole point behind OOP), you'd be better off creating an array.

Comment: @wasana do you really need it to be written to a file? Also if you just need to store some settings, consider creating an associative array and serialising / json_encoding that and store *that* in a file. Dynamically generating PHP code is *dangerous*

Comment: Can anyone give me an answer how to do this ? I'm new to OOP

Comment: @thaJeztah yes i need that.I need to save some settings.....

Comment: @I need to save some settings as a class.Like joomla configuration.php

Comment: @Wasana Where does 'adminConfig' come from?

Comment: $adminConfig  = new pard_admin_Config($title,$online,$offline,$email,$metadescription,
$metakeywords,$copyright,$pard_host,$pard_database,$username,$password);

Comment: __construct parameters pass values to this adminConfig object

Comment: I'll update the whole code wait guys ?

Comment: I updated the whole code....

Comment: @thaJeztah Is there anyone can help me to go though ?

Comment: Sorry, don't have the time at the moment, there's a lot to be written

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a simple object that represent your data you can use stdClass or associative array:

object:

```
$cls = new stdClass();
$cls->param = 'string';
$cls->{'param2'} = 12;
```

array:

```
$arr = array(
    'param'=> 'string',
    'param2' => 12
);
```

The advantage of stdClass that it is a "pure" php object and you can send it around your code by ref by default without setting & to pass it by ref in an array example.

The advantave of array is you can set it in one line.